# Why is this array not empty?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js

I trying to show a message in an array is empty in a filter method in Vue.
However, it seems my computed function still returns an array of empty object (If I search for something not there)

What I wish is that it only returns the object that actually has a value - the empty ones should be filtered out?

So if I search for "fjhdsfjsdfjsd" ex, it still return about 200 items, just empty objects, which it shouldnt?

The computed function looks like:

```
filteredAlarms: function () {

    let filter = {};
    let searchString = this.search_string.toLowerCase();

    Object.keys(this.eventLog).forEach(key => {
      filter[key] = this.eventLog[key].filter(item => {
        let systemName = item.system_name.toLowerCase();
        if(item.type.includes("alarm") && systemName.includes(searchString)) {
          return item;
        }
      });
    });

    return filter

  },
```

Comment: Notice that the `.filter` callback should return a boolean. Always. Not sometimes an item and sometimes undefined.

Comment: Can you provide some example input and the output you're getting for it, please? Your code should return an object of empty arrays, not the other way round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one. I hope this will work.

```
filteredAlarms: function () {

    let filter = {};
    let searchString = this.search_string.toLowerCase();

    Object.keys(this.eventLog).forEach(key => {
      filter[key] = this.eventLog[key].filter(function(item){
        return item.type.includes("alarm") && item.system_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchString);
      });
    });

    return filter

  },
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Parameters)** must return a boolean. Just remove the `if` and the `return item` part and just return your if condition:

```
filteredAlarms: function () {
  let searchString = this.search_string.toLowerCase();
  let eventKeys = Object.keys(this.eventLog);

  return eventKeys.reduce((filter, key) => {

    let items = this.eventLog[key].filter(item => {
      let systemName = item.system_name.toLowerCase();
      return item.type.includes("alarm") && systemName.includes(searchString);
    });

    return Object.assign(filter, { [key]: items });
  }, {});
}
```